# Trigger Test fails because check for roll-up field value in Trigger finds old value

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, failing-tests, roll-up-summary

I have a trigger on a custom object, Subscription__c, (child of Account) which is supposed to give the Account TelemarketingPrioritizedFor__c = 'Winback' if, and only if, the field NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c is 0 -- that field is a roll-up field which counts the number of Subscription__c with StartDate__c and NO EndDate__c (ie. EndDate__c = null).

Now, in my trigger test I want to add a subscription and then subsequently update it with an EndDate__c -- which should cause the trigger to fire and mark the Account as Winback. However, this doesn't happen as the NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c field remains '1' despite the only Subscription__c now having an EndDate__c. I know this is because Roll-up fields are not updated until after a trigger fires, but I don't know how to test the trigger properly then?

Here's the SubscriptionTrigger:

```
trigger SubscriptionTrigger on Subscription__c (after update) {
    /*
    * If the new sub has an EndDate and the old didn't, the sub just got cancelled.
    * In those cases, we should mark the Account as prioritized for Winback (causing the AccountTrigger to push them to Winback) and set a DCU of 3 months
    */

    System.debug('SubscriptionTrigger activated!');

    Id winbackId;
    List<Campaign> winback = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Type = 'Winback'];
    if (winback.size() > 0) winbackId = winback[0].Id;
    Id noshowId;
    List<Campaign> noshow = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Type = 'No show'];
    if (noshow.size() > 0) noshowId = noshow[0].Id;

    /*
    * By using a List we can have a single insert DML command instead of a bunch of separate ones. Keeps the governor happy.
    */
    List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    /*
    * We do this additional query in order to check whether the person is a permanent no or has other active subscriptions.
    * This avoids situations where a person is marked as Dead__c, then later has their Subscription terminated, and is accidentally added to Winback
    */
    Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for (Account a : [SELECT Id, TelemarketingPrioritizedFor__c, Dead__c, No_fundraising__c, NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new)]) {
        accMap.put(a.Id, a);
    }

    System.debug('SubscriptionTrigger will now check the Trigger subscriptions...');

    for (Subscription__c s : Trigger.new) {
        System.debug('SubscriptionTrigger checking a subscription...');
        Subscription__c oldSub = Trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id); 
        if (oldSub.EndDate__c == null && s.EndDate__c != null) {
            System.debug('SubscriptionTrigger found a Subscription that has been Ended! Its data is StartDate: ' + s.StartDate__c + ' and EndDate ' + s.EndDate__c + ' It will now check for permanent no on Account...');
            /*
            * Subscription just got cancelled. Provided that the person isn't a permanent no, prioritize him for winback
            */
            Account acc = accMap.get(s.Account__c);
            System.debug('SubscriptionTrigger digged up the responsible Account with these info: Dead: ' + acc.Dead__c + ' and NF: ' + acc.No_fundraising__c + ' and NOAS: ' + acc.NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c);
            if (acc.Dead__c == false && acc.No_fundraising__c == false && acc.NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c == 0) {
                System.debug('SubscriptionTrigger found no permanent nos and is prioritizing for Winback...');
                acc.TelemarketingPrioritizedFor__c = 'Winback';
                accsToUpdate.add(acc);
            } 
        }
    }

    if (accsToUpdate.size() > 0) update accsToUpdate;
}
```

and here is the test class for it:

```
@isTest
public class SubscriptionTriggerTest {

    @isTest
    static void endingSubscriptionPrioritizesAccountForWinback() {

        // Setup
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Person');
        insert acc;
        Contact con = new Contact(AccountId = acc.Id, FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Person');
        insert con;
        Campaign winback = new Campaign(Name = 'Winback', Type = 'Winback');
        insert winback;

        // Add Subscription
        Subscription__c sub = new Subscription__c(Account__c = acc.Id, Amount__c = 100, StartDate__c = Date.today().addDays(-10));
        insert sub;

        // Adding EndDate should make the trigger prioritize the Account for Winback
        sub.EndDate__c = Date.today();
        update sub;

        Account actual = [SELECT Id, TelemarketingPrioritizedFor__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals('Winback', acc.TelemarketingPrioritizedFor__c);
    }
}
```

The error I get when running the test is:

```
SubscriptionTriggerTest.endingSubscriptionPrioritizesAccountForWinback  System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Winback, Actual: null
                                                                        /home/mp/code/salesforcedx/force-app/main/default/classes/SubscriptionTriggerTest.cls:30:1
```

as mentioned, this is due to the NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c field being == 1 and thus the Account is never updated.

Answer (score 3):

You used `acc` instead of `actual` for the test, so it was guaranteed to fail. Here's what you meant to write:

```
System.assertEquals('Winback', actual.TelemarketingPrioritizedFor__c);
```

If you look at the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) document, you'll see that since the Subscription was updated, the parent's rollup summary field (the account) *will be correct* at that point in your trigger.

In this case, it was a simple case of using the wrong variable. This effect happens because the database and the current transaction are considered two different areas of memory. Whatever you put in a sObject variable is only temporary and does not necessarily reflect the state of the database.

Comment: Damn, such a bad mistake... Anyway, even after fixing it the original problem persists: When the trigger fires, it still evaluates `NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c` to being 1. Looking at your link, it seems like during the test trigger fires at Step 7, but the `NumberOfActiveSubscriptions__c` Roll-up isn't updated until Step 17? Isn't that why this test fails? And is there anything I can do to get around that problem?